# Network or Active Directory Required Resources Not Available

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory, system-center, mom

Using Microsoft System Center I continually have the following errors.

```
Alert: Network or Active Directory Required Resources Not Available
Source: DC-SMS01.hq.gratisinc.com
Path: 
Last modified by: System
Last modified time: 5/13/2009 12:10:24 PM
Alert description: Windows cannot obtain the domain controller name for your computer network. (An unexpected network error occurred. ). Group Policy processing aborted.
```

We have Domain Controllers all over the place, they are happy and in sync.  FSMO roles are spread out, and the network links are all fast and not saturated.

Anyone have this issue? If so how did you solve it?

Comment: I'm surprised there's no SCCM or MOM or SCOM tags yet.

Comment: I agree.  I need to be 100 before I can add them I think..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we have similar problems it almost always seems to trace back to DNS.  Make sure your DNS records for all of the involved devices are ship-shape in both directions.